# Pre-defining number format of a data frame in R

Tags: r, format

Is there any way to pre-define a number format (e.g. rounding off to the specified number of decimal places)  of a data frame so that whenever I add a new column it follows the same format?

I tried with `format {base}`, but it only changes the format of the existing columns not for the ones I add after.

A workable example is given below

```
mydf <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(50), ncol=5))
mydf
           V1          V2         V3          V4          V5
1  -1.3088022 -0.22088032 -1.8739405  1.65276442  1.21762297
2   1.1123253 -0.76042101 -0.1608188  0.39945804 -0.58674209
3  -0.9366654  0.92893610 -0.6905299 -0.37374892 -1.70539909
4   0.4619175 -0.28929198  1.0280021 -0.87998207 -0.34493824
5  -0.3741670 -0.61782368 -1.0435906  0.52166082 -0.29308408
6  -1.2283031 -0.37065379  0.8652538  0.05088202 -1.80997313
7  -1.1137726 -0.97878307  0.5045051  0.85442196  0.02932812
8   0.3373866 -0.46614754 -0.4642278 -0.38438002 -1.47251777
9   0.3245720 -0.06047061 -0.3273080  0.49145133 -0.86507348
10  1.6459180 -1.31076464  1.5627246  0.49841764  0.73895626
```

the following changes the format of the data frame

```
mydf <- format(mydf, digits=2)
mydf
      V1    V2    V3     V4     V5
1  -1.31 -0.22 -1.87  1.653  1.218
2   1.11 -0.76 -0.16  0.399 -0.587
3  -0.94  0.93 -0.69 -0.374 -1.705
4   0.46 -0.29  1.03 -0.880 -0.345
5  -0.37 -0.62 -1.04  0.522 -0.293
6  -1.23 -0.37  0.87  0.051 -1.810
7  -1.11 -0.98  0.50  0.854  0.029
8   0.34 -0.47 -0.46 -0.384 -1.473
9   0.32 -0.06 -0.33  0.491 -0.865
10  1.65 -1.31  1.56  0.498  0.739
```

but this formatting is not applied when I add a new column to the data frame, see below

```
mydf$new <- rnorm(10)
mydf
      V1    V2    V3     V4     V5         new
1  -1.31 -0.22 -1.87  1.653  1.218  0.30525117
2   1.11 -0.76 -0.16  0.399 -0.587 -1.83038790
3  -0.94  0.93 -0.69 -0.374 -1.705  0.34830499
4   0.46 -0.29  1.03 -0.880 -0.345 -0.66017888
5  -0.37 -0.62 -1.04  0.522 -0.293  0.03103741
6  -1.23 -0.37  0.87  0.051 -1.810  1.32809006
7  -1.11 -0.98  0.50  0.854  0.029  0.85428977
8   0.34 -0.47 -0.46 -0.384 -1.473 -0.51917266
9   0.32 -0.06 -0.33  0.491 -0.865 -0.37057104
10  1.65 -1.31  1.56  0.498  0.739 -1.32447706
```

I know I can adjust the digits using `print {base}`, but that also does not change the underlying format of the data frame. Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: By calling `format` you're actually changing the underlying data. It's no longer numeric and has been converted to character. As noted above you can changed the printing defaults by setting the digits option, and keep everything numeric.

Comment: Yeah. I noticed that format changes numeric to character. So there is no way I can predefine the underlying number format of a data frame? All I can do is adjust the printing format, either by changing the default settings using the `option` or by defining it every time using `print`?